# NullPointerException From Solr UpdateLog v4.8

Tags: solr, nullpointerexception, solrj

I was trying to update a bunch of documents in Solr and commit them:
I got this error (It's been working for a long time.)

I have a setup of multiple cores and I'm updating docs from a bunch of the.
I commit all the cores I change.

Once I stop and start my solr again I can add and commit the object and it works fine.

Any idea whats wrong?

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.lookup(UpdateLog.java:706)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.RealTimeGetComponent.getInputDocumentFromTlog(RealTimeGetComponent.java:217)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.RealTimeGetComponent.getInputDocument(RealTimeGetComponent.java:242)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.getUpdatedDocument(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:892)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:791)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:557)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:96)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:166)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:136)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:228)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:121)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:193)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:119)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:173)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:106)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:58)
at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1953)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:774)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:953)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, it's not the same. the code in that line is: if (entry !=null)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use solr's add or addBean methods

try this

```
        String jsonString =
                "{\"id\":\"1\", \"title\":\"Example Document\", \"description\":\"This is an example document for Solr\"}";

        // Create Solr client
        SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();

        try {
            // Create a ContentStreamUpdateRequest
              ContentStreamUpdateRequest request =
                    new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update");

            ContentStream contentStream =
                    new ContentStreamBase.StringStream(json, "application/json");
            request.addContentStream(contentStream);

            UpdateResponse response = request.process(solrClient);

            // Commit the changes
            solrClient.commit();

            System.out.println(
                    "JSON document uploaded to Solr successfully. Response status: " +
                            response.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Close Solr client
            if (solrClient != null) {
                try {
                    solrClient.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).